# Converting non-standard dates in r

Tags: r, date

My date information is a string in the following format: 3/12/1956 0:00:00

I have tried converting it using DOB<-as.Date(DOB, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")

I am trying to convert it for the purpose of then applying the age_calc function in eeptools package.

Is there some other way to change a non standard format into a date. Damn Aussie dates!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `lubridate` as an alternative

```
library(lubridate)
DOB <- '3/12/1956 0:00:00'
mdy_hms(DOB)
#[1] "1956-03-12 UTC"
```

It can also take `multiple` formats

```
 DOB <- c('3/12/1956 0:00:00', '3.12/1956 0.00/00')
 mdy_hms(DOB)
#[1] "1956-03-12 UTC" "1956-03-12 UTC"
```

Or as @Richard Scriven commented,

```
as.Date(DOB, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
#[1] "1956-12-03"
```